# Refused to load the font '<URL>' for a font in google maps

Tags: http-headers, content-security-policy, google-fonts

On configuring the content-security-policy of a site, I'm setting the font source in combination with styles like this

```
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' fonts.googleapis.com;
font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com;
```

This works in Firefox for all cases. However, Chromium complains when google maps tries to fetch the roboto font:

```
Refused to load the font '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com".
Refused to load the font 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fCRc4EsA.woff2' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com".
```

I've tried adding *'unsafe-inline'* and *data:* as scheme source, but none seem to do the trick. I'm confused about why Chromium reports font `"<URL>"`, it doesn't seem to be an [accepted scheme source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/font-src) and I don't get why it's been blocked

Comment: Based on the error, the font-src is `font-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com`... are you sure you have `fonts.gstatic.com` in your `font-src`?

Comment: yes, although error is now gone. I had to use a more generous policy for google maps